# Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'socialdb'

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

I've seen a few errors like this, but I found no answer.

```
Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'socialdb'
```

socialdb is my database. The "Unable to connect to database:" part is located here.

```
$db = mysql_select_db("socialdb",$con);

if(!$db) {

    die ('Unable to connect to database: ' . mysql_error());

    }
```

I don't know what's causing this. Here are my mysql_connect details

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost");

if(!$con) {

    die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

    }
```

I need to find the root. Thanks.

I DON'T HAVE A USERNAME OR PASSWORD FOR MySQL

Should it be this?

```
mysql_connect("localhost","","");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you're not allowed to connect without specifying some credentials.

Change your call to [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) to something like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
```

Comment: I don't have a username or password for it though

Comment: Then create a user. See the syntax for `CREATE USER` and `GRANT`. [MySQL 5.5 Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/)

Comment: @user1226076 you do, you just don't know it. Take a look at MySQL's configuration, or try to log in using some management tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench.

Comment: You always have a username but maybe your password is empty. Probably your username is 'root' with an empty '' password if this is a fresh local installation

Comment: Yeah, this is a local installation

Comment: In that cases as Kypros mentioned, it's probably username root and password is empty

Comment: Kypros, thank you. I entered root as my username and I got it to be successful. Thank you! (How do I get a comment to be the right answer?)

Comment: @user1226076 you can't. And don't ever access your database as root. Ever.

Comment: @user1226076 because the root account can do anything on your database. Even the slightest bug on your web site (have you ever heard of SQL injection?) will allow anyone to read or delete your whole database.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of SQL injection. I may not know the most about coding, but I'm not mind-blank.

Comment: Wait, so is this the SQL code for a new user? CREATE USER username;

Comment: @user1226076 please read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your default credentials are most likely:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

Comment: I did $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");

Answer (score 0):

You're missing username and password parameter, should be:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

Comment: I don't have a username or password

Comment: how did you create the database?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a user in neither `mysql_connect` or your PHP configuration.

Either set `mysql.default_user` and `mysql.default_password` in your PHP configuration or use the appropriate arguments for `mysql_connect`.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect takes 3 parameters

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

even if you are not having a user. there exist 'root' user 
so use it

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
```