# PHP script to connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am running this script

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("ServerName", "username", "password", "dbname");
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from table1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['_msg'];
?>
```

I am getting this error:

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because
>   the target machine actively refused it

I have looked around online, but I can't figure out what is wrong. All the credentials are correct and it still doesn't work.

I am connecting to a local db on SQL Server through SQL Server authentication. Do I need MySQL running on xamp for this to work? Any ideas?

I am using Windows 10 through bootcamp on a mac. This is for SQL Server, not for mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'socialdb'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397533/unable-to-connect-to-database-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database)

Comment: @ZainFarooq i have entered my credentials correctly though and it still doesnt work

Comment: By `SQL Server` do you mean MSSQL? Note that `mysqli` is only for connecting to MySQL instances.

Comment: mysqli is used to connect to a MySql. MS SQL Server is not MySql.

Comment: type this `if($mysqli){echo "Connected";} else{echo mysqli_connect_errno();}`

Comment: It would be due to port problems... there would be conflict better your port on local machine

Comment: If you're connecting to MSSQL then use PDO don't use `mysqli` api

Comment: @SaadSuri i tried using PDO already but mssql_connect has been removed from php 7.2

Comment: Do you use Windows 10 and MS SQL as Server?

Comment: Use this extension https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: @Gabor yes, i use windows 10 + ms sql

Comment: The standard method is a Linux + MySQL or a Windows Server + MSSQL. Windows 10 is a client side OS. WinServer+MSSQL for web is a very sensible system with many possible errors. For web-development is recommended a LAMP Server.

Comment: @Gabor what is the difference from xamp?

Comment: XAMP is a software-emulated Apache-MySQL-PHP Server. LAMP is a Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) based computer with Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin linux-package. 90% of hosting companies use Linux server (CentOs, Debian, Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database. In this case maybe this code helps:

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Also, if you run your php server locally with XAMPP you need to have Apache activated. If you try to connect to a MS SQL Server database you dont have to have MySQL enabled since you are not trying to connect to a MySQL database.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)